# Issue with Connecting to PPTP VPN - Modem hangup

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, pptp, networkmanager

I have following issue with connection to PPTP VPN in Ubuntu 14.04.

1. I installed ppp and ppp-linux
2. I set up /etc/ppp/chap-secrets to following

   ```
   113.41.242.167\\mark    PPTP    NaksOsP    *
   ```
3. I created /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1 with following

   ```
   pty "pptp 113.41.242.167 --nolaunchpppd"                                    
   name 113.41.242.167\\mark                                
   remotename PPTP                                
   require-mppe-128                                
   file /etc/ppp/options.pptp                                
   ipparam vpn1                                
   mru 1412                                
   mtu 1412
   ```
4. I edited /etc/ppp/options.pptp to following

   ```
   lock
   noauth
   refuse-pap
   refuse-eap
   refuse-chap
   refuse-mschap-v2
   nobsdcomp
   nodeflate
   ```
5. Then I run sudo pon vpn1 with no response, so I ran sudo pon vpn1 debug dump logfd 2 nodetach with following output

   ```
   pppd options in effect:
   debug       # (from command line)
   nodetach        # (from command line)
   logfd 2     # (from command line)
   dump        # (from command line)
   noauth      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   refuse-pap      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   refuse-chap     # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   refuse-mschap-v2        # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   refuse-eap      # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   name 113.41.242.167\\mark       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   remotename PPTP     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
           # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   pty pptp 113.41.242.167 --nolaunchpppd      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   crtscts     # (from /etc/ppp/options)
           # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   asyncmap 0      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   mru 1412        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   mtu 1412        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   lcp-echo-failure 4      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   lcp-echo-interval 30        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   hide-password       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   ipparam vpn1        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   nobsdcomp       # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   nodeflate       # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
   require-mppe-128        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/vpn1)
   noipx       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
   using channel 28
   Using interface ppp0
   Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/22
   sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1412> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc953e228> <pcomp> <accomp>]
   sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1412> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc953e228> <pcomp> <accomp>]
   Modem hangup
   Connection terminated.
   Script pptp 113.41.242.167 --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 8753), status = 0x0
   ```

Can anyone please help me with this ? I also tried Network Manager GUI but with no luck